# Get sharing settings of the organization using the API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-admin-settings-api

Is it possible to retrieve (or change) google drive's sharing settings using the API?
I don't want to share a file, but to see the organization's settings, as described here:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/60781?hl=en

If so, what are the required scopes that I need?
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand really well what you would like to do. Do you want to share a whole Drive or just some files with other users in your organisation? Like having a shared Drive with some custom shared settings? Could you please give an example?

Comment: No, I want to query the "sharing settings" of the organization, as described in the link I added. For example, I want to know know systemically and programmatically whether people in the organization can share files with anyone, or just with people on the organization.

Answer (score 0):

The google Drive API is a file system API,  it gives you access to files.

It does not give you access to change the settings for the Google Drive web application.

You could go in with the drive api and chance the permissions on directories and files in drive and maybe control some things that way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
What about other APIs? Such as directory API, admin API, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it's not possible to do it programmatically As the [Directory API: Limits and Quotas](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits) in [Api Limits and Quotas](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits#api-limits-and-quotas) states:

> Groups, settings: 
>   Groups access settings, sharing options, monitoring,
>   and discussion archive is managed using the Admin console. For more
>   information about groups settings, see the [administration help
>   center](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33329?topic=14869&ctx=topic).

Comment: That refers to "Google Groups" which is a completely different service.
For example, I want to know with whom the users in the organization can share files with. Is it just other members of the organization? Is it anyone? A whitelist of domains?

Comment: There is no API for that, you could apply the ideas @DalmTo gave you.

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately, the thing that's important to me are the drive's sharing permissions. I want to see wether users can share things internally, with anyone, or with a whitelist of domains. So even though I appreciate @DalmTo's suggestions, they are not quite what I'm looking for.
Thank you